# How to compile and run LISP project?

Tags: debugging, compilation, lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I am new to LISP, currently using LispWorks and ListBox IDE on window server 2008.
I want to know that, how can we compile and run LISP project, contain 350 LISP source file.
and what will be generate after compilation and how can i run it...?
and what's techniques are available to debug lisp project.
(it is old technology, so I cannot get much help from internet)

Comment: Typically Lisp is not compiled & run in the same style as a C++ program. Debugging can be done with BREAK or TRACE. Beyond that, I am not familiar with LispWorks, but can simply point you to their web page: http://www.lispworks.com/kb/index.html

Comment: Lisp is not old technology, and there is plenty of material about it on the internet.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: LispWorks includes all the tools to create typical applications, similar to a C++ program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LispWorks comes with a lot of documentation. This documentation is also available on their [website](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/index.html).

LispWorks can:

- organize source code with a system management tool
- save images with saved state
- compile individual files to loadable machine code
- create shared libraries
- create stand-alone applications

Their [Delivery User Guide](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/DV/html/delivery.htm) describes how to generate applications.
The documentation of [DEFSYSTEM](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/LW/html/lw-303.htm#pgfId-884853) describes how to organize source code and how to compile systems.